# SQl Server deadlock with simple update statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, database-deadlocks

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 I am getting deadlocks when the same update statement (with different parameters) is running concurrently. Here is the deadlock graph  (sorry cannot post images on here yet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6JBK.png

And here is the actual execution plan:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/emm9i.png

The update is like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE mapping.IssuerAlternateName
SET
    UseCount = UseCount + 1,
    MostRecentlyAppeared = GETDATE(),
    MostRecentlyAppearedUnderlyingAssetName = @p1
WHERE ID = @p0
',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=1234,@p1=N'blah blah blah'
```

If I have understood things correctly we are trying to read and write from the same index `(PK_IssuerAlternateName_1)`.

Is there any way to resolve this? I was wondering if adding an additional index to the primary key and using WITH INDEX might fix it by stopping the read of `PK_IssuerAlternateName_1` (sorry the full name is truncated in the execution plan screenshot).

Or is the best option just to live with this and retry the transaction, which is how the error is currently handled in .NET client. It is certainly successful on retry, but it would be good to avoid the deadlock if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Are you currently wrapping this in a transaction? If so, which isolation level are you using?

Comment: Calling it using LINQ2SQL so context.ExecuteCommand()...

Answer (score 0):

In situations similar to this, I have used the `UPDLOCK` hint to let the database know I intend to update this row. It is not implied by the `UPDATE` statement. Without the lock hint, it will first obtain a "shared" lock, and then try to escalate. However, this causes deadlocks in certain scenarios.

You will need to do this within your own `TransactionScope` to ensure everything works correctly.

```
var sql = @"UPDATE mapping.IssuerAlternateName with (UPDLOCK)
SET
    UseCount = UseCount + 1,
    MostRecentlyAppeared = GETDATE(),
    MostRecentlyAppearedUnderlyingAssetName = @p1
WHERE ID = @p0";

var options = new TransactionOptions()
{
    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted // don't use Serializable!
};

using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, options))
{
    using (var context = new YourDbContext())
    {
        // execute your command here 
    }
}
```

Comment: So if it gets an update lock as opposed to a shared lock, the next process will just wait for this statement to finish before starting? Sorry, I am no DBA...

Comment: Yes. And I'm not DBA either. I've just had a similar experience in a queue environment.